# Re-init Materialize.css select box after removal from Knockout.js options array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, materialize

I have a select box where the options and selection are handled via Knockout.js. I want to style this using Materialize CSS.

This works OK for the initial display of the select box, and when options are added to the Knockout.js 'options' observableArray by using the 'optionsAfterRender' binding to (re)initialize after each option has been added (wasteful, but works).

When removing an option, Knockout.js does not provide anything similar to 'optionsAfterRender', so there is no obvious way to trigger a re-initialization of the Materialize CSS magic.

Question: Are there any non-insane options which you can see?

Code:

```
<select data-bind="

      options: options,
      optionsText: function(item) { return optionsText[item] },
      value: displayedValue,

      optionsAfterRender: function (option, item) {
         setTimeout(function() {
            $(option.parentElement).material_select();
         }, 0);
      }
     ">
</select>
```

(The 'setTimeout' is necessary since otherwise the selected option is not picked.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) is more appropriate for integrating a custom UI component like `material_select` with KnockoutJS. Here's one way to build such a handler:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers["materializeSelect"] = {
  after: ['options'],
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // Initial initialization:
    $(element).material_select();
    
    // Find the "options" sub-binding:
    var boundValue = valueAccessor();
    
    // Register a callback for when "options" changes:
    boundValue.options.subscribe(function() {
      $(element).material_select();
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    
  }
};

function RootViewModel() {
  var self = this, i = 2;
  self.options = ko.observableArray([{id: 1, txt: "Option A"}, {id: 2, txt: "Option two"}]);
  self.selectedOption = ko.observable(null);
  
  // For testing purposes:
  self.addOption = function() { self.options.push({id: ++i, txt: "Dynamic option " + i}); };
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.4/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.4/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select data-bind="materializeSelect: { options: options },
                   options: options,
                   optionsText: 'txt',
                   value: selectedOption">
</select>

<button data-bind="click: addOption">Add option dynamically</button>
```

To be honest, I feel it's an issue/omission or perhaps even a bug in MaterializeCSS that it apparently doesn't notice `select` options changing. IIRC libraries like Select2 and Chosen *do* have this feature.

In any case, if MaterializeCSS *would* notice dynamically added options correctly, I'd still stuggest using a custom binding handler, only a much simpler one:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers["materializeSelect"] = {
  after: ['options'],
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    $(element).material_select();
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // Handle ViewModel changes of which MaterializeCSS needs custom
    // notification here.
  }
};
```

Comment: I usually call `.material_select('destroy');` before reinit just to be sure. materializecss is a bit young imho

Comment: Thanks for a perfectly working answer - which also solved the next problem I had, how to re-init after value changes in the KO model!

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen's answer is great and correct, I wanted to add an addendum using SO comments, but this is better seen with full formatting, I think.

Materialize seems to be a bit weird responding to the  `disable` binding when placed on a select, particularly if that disable is reliant on the updating of another knockout observable (which it usually is).

I use the following in my update function:

```
if(allBindings().disable != undefined && allBindings().disable == true){
   $(element).prop("disabled", true);
}
else{
   $(element).prop("disabled", false);     
}

$(element).material_select();
```

I initially tried just calling `$(element).material_select()` in the update function, but it seems a little wishy washy, only working some of the time. Explicitly changing the disabled property on the element seems to work every time.

There's likely a much more succinct way to do this, but hopefully this example illustrates the point: explicitly set the disabled property based on the state of the binding.

I don't know if similar problems are encountered using other bindings, `visible` etc., but if they are, those problems can likely be solved in a similar fashion.