# knockoutjs and materializecss javascript dropdown

Tags: knockout.js, materialize

When I try and use a materializecss javascript dropdown (http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html) within code that is being dynamically generated by a knockoutjs foreach binding, the dropdown options do not show up when the drop down trigger is clicked.

```
<ul class="list" data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
    <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' 
             data-bind="attr: {'data-activates': 'dropdown' + $index()}">Drop Me!</a>
    <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
    <ul data-bind="attr: {id: 'dropdown' + $index()}" class='dropdown-content'>
      <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Materializecss says the dropdown must be initialized with

```
$(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
```

However, this seems to have no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.  I have not been able to find help within knockoutjs forums or elsewhere.

EDIT - a complete working model

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script  >
        function ItemsViewModel() {
            var that = this;

            function collectionItem(root, title) {
                var self = this;
                self.title = ko.observable(title);
            };

            that.items = ko.observableArray();
            that.loadItems = function () {
                for (var i = 0, j = 5; i < j; i++) {
                   that.items.push(new collectionItem(that,"title"+ i.toString()));
                }
            };
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.materializeDropdown = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                $(element).dropdown();
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
            }
        };

        var itemsViewModel;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            itemsViewModel = new ItemsViewModel();

            ko.applyBindings(itemsViewModel,      $("#divForItemsViewModel").get(0));
            itemsViewModel.loadItems();
        });
    </script>
    <div id="divForItemsViewModel">
         <ul class="list" data-bind="foreach: items">
            <li>
                <div data-bind="text:title"></div>
                <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
                <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#'
                   data-bind="attr: {'data-activates': 'dropdown' + $index()}, materializeDropdown">Drop Me!</a>
                <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
                <ul data-bind="attr: {id: 'dropdown' + $index()}" class='dropdown-content'>
                    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#'
       data-activates="dropdownx">Drop Me THIS WORKS</a>
        <ul id="dropdownx" class='dropdown-content'>
            <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your *question* is technically not a dupe, but I'd nearly ad verbatim repeat [this answer I wrote some time ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34394679/419956).

Comment: Thank you Jeroen.  Yes before posting this question I studied your answer and I just tried Fede's custom binding but it didn't seem to help. The key to linking the trigger to the content is the data-activates binding on the trigger and the id binding on the target.  The values have to be the same.  I think I'm setting those correctly.

Comment: Using a custom binding for integrating this UI plugin is just about mandatory. Initializing it as you do will as far as I'd guess never really work. In either case (with or without custom binding), it would be helpful if you can extend the question's code into an [mcve].

Comment: Thank you Jeroen I have added an example.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need here is a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). What I believe is happening is that when `$(".dropdown-button").dropdown();` is invoked, the `foreach` binding may not have executed, and thus the values of the dropdown aren't available yet.

I would move the `ul` for the dropdown structure before the `a` tag of the dropdown trigger, in order to be sure that any binding in the structure is run before the bindings in the trigger. Then add your custom binding to the trigger, that when invoked performs the `.dropdown()` on the target.

**EDIT**

Here is a sample of the suggested custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.materializeDropdown = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).dropdown();
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    }
};
```

And then the html could be as follows.

```
<ul class="list" data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
    <ul data-bind="attr: {id: 'dropdown' + $index()}" class='dropdown-content'>
      <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
    <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' 
             data-bind="attr: {'data-activates': 'dropdown' + $index()}, materializeDropdown">Drop Me!</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Fede - Just to point out that running   $(".dropdown-button").dropdown(); is an intialization step - not a method to trigger the dropdown so I don't really see the need for a custom binding.  Instead, as a test, after the page is rendered I click a link which runs $(".dropdown-button").dropdown(); to intialize any dropdowns.  However this seems to have no affect.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the use of custom binding.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with a sample, though if you are already running the `$(".dropdown-button").dropdown();` manually after bindings, then I'm out of ideas. I'll update my answer anyway just for completeness.

Comment: Thanks Fede for taking the trouble to include the sample code.  Sadly using a custom binding didn't seem to make any difference.